# Socket.io client only joins room on every other connection

Tags: socket.io, socket.io-1.0

I've been trying to make a basic notification system that uses rooms in Socket.io. However, for some reason, it only works every other time you refresh the page.

I've simplified the code to make it easier to debug, but the issue remains. Each time I refresh the page, everything seems to work except joining a room (which only works half the time). What could be going on?

edit: I'm using Socket.io version 1.1.0 and Node.js version 0.10.31
edit2: Added FunnyLookinHat's suggestion (but it still doesn't solve the problem)

**Client-Side Code:**

```
socket = io.connect('example.com:8081'),

socket.on('connect', function () {
    socket.on('startup', function(data) {
        console.log(data.message);
    });
    socket.emit('joinRoom');
});
```

**Server-Side Code:**

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(8081);

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {

    console.log(socket.id + ' connected!');

    socket.emit('startup', { message: 'Socket started!' });

    socket.on('joinRoom', function(){
        console.log(socket.id + ' joining room lobby'); // prints on every other request
        socket.join('lobby');
    });

    socket.on('disconnect', function() {
        console.log(socket.id + ' disconnected!');
    });

});
```

**Client Console:**

```
Socket started!

(refreshed page)

Socket started!
```

**Server Console:**

```
UIBqVuOiF1fegMIMAAAB connected!
UIBqVuOiF1fegMIMAAAB joining room lobby
UIBqVuOiF1fegMIMAAAB disconnected!

(refreshed page)

x3nMilBOjjFVjBFJAAAC connected!

(after about a minute once the client window has been closed or refreshed)

x3nMilBOjjFVjBFJAAAC disconnected!
```

Comment: I had similar issues, maybe some nasty CORS stuff under the hood, but I'm not sure. Are you opening the same thing in browser and connecting to the same site? (`socket = io.connect('example.com:8081')`) Note that having or not having `www` is also important.

Comment: I just got fed up with Socket.io. I switched to using Faye sockets, and I haven't had a problem since!

Answer (score 2):

Race condition!  Try doing the following in your client code:

```
socket = io.connect('example.com:8081'),

socket.on('connect', function () {
    socket.on('startup', function(data) {
        console.log(data.message);
    });

    socket.emit('joinRoom');
});
```

Comment: Good catch, however, the problem still exists after I make that fix. It still seems to be something else.

Comment: (To reduce confusion, I'll update the question with this fix since it doesn't solve the main issue.)